# pySpark - avoid processing single row at time

Tags: apache-spark, numpy-ndarray

I am using a propriety function that gets a NumPy `ndarray` vector, and gives another `ndarray` of the same length as results.

**Using Spark map**, I can run this function **on each row** of my input data, which is not efficient because the function processes vectors of one element each time.

Is it possible to process bulks of data in Spark? having, for example, (big) part of the input data on one machine, and other part of the data on another machine, could I feed all the rows available on each machine at once to my function as an `ndarray` for efficient calculation?

Comment: Spark will process individual units, then combine the outputs and process together as another work unit... Not sure if that's what youre trying to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what types of calculations you need to perform.

`mapPartitions` can process each larger chunk, but internally to that block you still would use `map` or other operations to transform your data.

Note: If you are comparing Spark to Numpy, though, you would be using DataFrame operations in SparkSQL and all data is transparently shuffled between servers for you.

If you have two DataFrames, you would probably join them before performing any operations.

Behind the scenes, there is no way to avoid looking at each element, whether you aggregate, transform, or otherwise collect back to a local collection.

Comment: mapPartitions seems to be the direction I am looking for. It allows to aggregate all the data in a partition: iterate on all the elements of the partition, build ndarray and feed it to the propriety function.

Comment: While searching I encountered glom method, what is the difference between mapPartitions and glom ?

Comment: The calculation being performed are not important, the point is that there is a propriety function that processes faster a batch of data rather than single elements.

Comment: I'm personally not familiar with glom, but again, I feel like you should be using SparkSql dataframe operations, not manually iterating over partitions